# Python Selenium decipher error message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to track down an error in Python Selenium.  The error message is..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\myscipt\main.py", line 110, in <module>
    source_mysource(func1, func2, func3, func4, func5, func6, func7, func8, func9)
  File "C:\myscipt\sources\functions.py", line 132, in source_mysource
    current_url = driver.current_url
  File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 454, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.
<super: <class 'WebDriverException'>, <UnexpectedAlertPresentException object>>
```

Is the error saying that the line current_url = driver.current_url is the one that is triggering the error or is it the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.current_url` property of a WebDriver instance, a `GET_CURRENT_URL` webdriver command is sent, which is triggering an error in your case. What happens is, the currently opened web-page is not the current top-level browsing context because of the alert being present, and, according to the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#get-current-url), it should and fails with an error.

In other words, current URL cannot be retrieved when there is an opened active alert.

Comment: I think I follow, so its not the get_current_url that is the error, it's just that it's highlighting the error.  So I guess I need to look is causing the alert to be present

Comment: @fightstarr20 yeah, the error happens on the `current_url = driver.current_url` line. You should look into why there is an alert shown at this moment.

Comment: Its a strange one, I don't actually see an error in the browser.  I can see the browser tab in the taskbar flashing blue which would normally indicate an error or alert but there is nothing there

Comment: @fightstarr20 what if you would try taking a screenshot before getting the `current_url`? Try putting `driver.save_screenshot("test.png")` right before the `current_url = driver.current_url` line. What do you see on the image?